# Specflow - How to use combination of multiple tables in scenario

Tags: c#, .net, bdd, specflow

I am using Specflow to perform BDD tests.  I am trying to test my navigation menu on multiple browsers.  Particularly making sure that buttons are showing up accross browsers. I do not want to create a bunch of tests for each menu item specifically on each browser and I do not want to create a large table that goes over every browser/menu item combination.  Is there any way to specify 2 tables and then create a single scenario that performs the combinations of both?

For example:

**Menu Items Table**

```
| menuItem |
| Home     |
| About    |
| Contact  |
```

**Browsers Table**

```
| browser |
| Chrome  |
| Firefox |
| IE      |
```

**Scenario**

```
Scenario Outline: I can see menu item
    Given I navigate to the "/" page using <browser>
    Then I can see the menu item <menuItem>
```

The expected result is that when this is run it would run 9 tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I prefer enlisting all of the combinations. It can happen that one or two is not needed or you need to specify special expected values for each, etc.:

```
Scenario: Flat scenario
    Given I have the following config:
    | menuItem | browser |
    | Home     | Chrome  |
   #| Home     | IE      | - ok, this is not needed
    | Home     | Firefox |
    | About    | Chrome  |
    | About    | IE      |
    | About    | Firefox |
    | Contact  | Chrome  |
    | Contact  | IE      |
    | Contact  | Firefox |
    Then something happens
```

If you really want to create full combinations I would use Scenario Outline with examples:

```
Scenario Outline: Combined scenario
    Given I have the following config:
    | MenuItem | Browser   |
    | Home     | <browser> |
    | About    | <browser> |
    | Contact  | <browser> |
    Then something happens

    Examples:
    | browser |
    | Chrome  |
    | Firefox |
    | IE      |
```

**Update:**

In the underlying method the last parameter can be a `Table`. So in the example above you can get the table as follows:

```
[Given(@"I have the following config:")]
public void InitFromConfiguration(Table table)
{
    // now the table has MenuItem and Browser columns
}
```

Considering browser is constant for one test case I would change it as follows:

```
Scenario Outline: Even better combined scenario
    Given I have the following items in the specified <browser>:
    | MenuItem |
    | Home     |
    | About    |
    | Contact  |
    When I test the browser with the given menuItems
    Then I have no errors

    Examples:
    | browser |
    | Chrome  |
    | Firefox |
    | IE      |

[Given(@"I have the following items in the specified (.*):")]
public void InitFromConfiguration(string browser, Table menuItems)
{
    // now the browser comes from the Examples and menuItems has 3 rows
}
```

You can even define a transform step for menu items if you prefer strong types instead of `Table`:

```
[Binding]
public class MyTransformations
{
    [StepArgumentTransformation]
    public MenuItem[] ToMenuItems(Table table)
    {
        return table.Rows.Select(row => new MenuItem(row[0])).ToArray();
    }        
}
```

And now you can define your `Given` as follows:

```
[Given(@"I have the following items in the specified (.*):")]
public void InitFromConfiguration(string browser, MenuItem[] menuItems)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Set(browser, nameof(browser));
    ScenarioContext.Current.Set(menuItems, nameof(menuItems));
}
```

Do the test itself in the `When` step. This is how you will call `DoTest` 9 times after all:

```
[When(@"I test the (.*) with the given (.*)")]
public void InitFromConfiguration(string browserKey, string menuItemsKey)
{
    var browser = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<string>(browserKey);
    var menuItems = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<MenuItem[]>(menuItemsKey);

    // TODO: in DoTest you can collect and save the possible errors in the context
    foreach (MenuItem mi in menuItems)
        DoTest(browser, mi);
}
```

And finally in the `Then` step you can assert the possible errors you collected and stored into the context in the `DoTest` method.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  I still end up with only 3 tests where it passes in the browsers but not the menu items.  I would expect it to give 9 tests.

Comment: Yes, it will be as many test cases as many Examples you have. But all 3 cases will have a `Table` with 3 rows in the `Given` step. So in each case you can iterate through the menu items with the current browser. If you really want 9 separate cases you must go with the flat version as Outline and each row should come from Examples.

Answer (score 0):

The test you want to write:

```
Scenario: I can see menu items
    Given I navigate to the "/" page
    Then I can see the menu items:
         | Home     |
         | About    |
         | Contact  |
```

You should be aiming for the same functionality across browsers anyway, so simply run the entire suite of tests for each browser.

In a config file, specify the browser you want to run and when you are building the driver, check which browser you want to run from the config.

Comment: If the expectation ("Then" statement) is the same across multiple browsers, there is no reason to separate the tests.

Comment: @Shiraz That's essentially what I've said in my answer. The journey shouldn't change too much, but running the tests across multiple browsers will ensure that the functionality isn't broken in any specific one. Browsers run on a variety of JS engines and HTML renderers, and if a snippet of javascript won't run or html won't render in the expected way for a browser that is popular with our users, we should fix it, and that's what I mean by "aiming for the same functionality across multiple browsers" - I'm just saying run a subsection of the suite, and just edit the config before you run it

Comment: Editing a config reduces the level of automation. "Configuration" should be driven from BDD definitions, hence having an Examples table for browsers.

Comment: You could set up a runner script for your test framework, and state the wanted browser as an argument there, and that could be used to override the config option.

That would mean, when hooking it up to your CI tool, you'll be able to state the browser, and run the suite more effectively in parallel. You could introduce a before hook to skip over tests that you don't want to be ran in that browser

The browser shouldn't be relevant to the user in most cases, and in the edge cases where it should make a difference, an overridable configuration file seems like a sensible option...