# Issue with automating 'Then' step BDD C# Specflow

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, bdd, specflow

I'm running a test where i'm validating an output from a file (e.g irm_xxx_lkdd_xuxt.csv.ovr) with my expected output "6677,6677_6677,3001,6"

The issue i'm having is my code below isn't being recognised by my specflow 'Then' step. I think the issue could be because i'm using Nunit testcase. Is there a way round this? or can i combine my file path and expected result within my ValidateMeasurement method

```
    [Then("Transfer measure should be generated for (.*)")]


[TestCase("irm_xxx_lkdd_xuxt.csv.ovr", "6677,6677_6677,3001,6")]
[TestCase("irm_xxx_lkdd_fcvt.csv.ovrr", "6677,6677_6677,3001,6")]
[TestCase("irm_xxx_lkdd_fbvt.csv.ovrr", "6677,6677_6677,3001,6")]

public void ValidateMeasurement(string path, string expected)
{
    const string processFilePath = "/orabin/app/product/inputs/ff/actuals/";
    var actual = Common.LinuxCommandExecutor
                       .RunLinuxcommand($"cat {processFilePath}{path}");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

}



Given I Loaded LifeCycle Measurement for Current
And Inventory interface is generated 
When Inventory batch is executed
Then Transfer measure should be generated Current
Examples:
| Lifecyclestatus |
| PreNew          |
| New             |
| Current         |
| Clearance       |
| Old             |
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not mix BDD and NUnit test cases. The Specflow generates NUnit tests in the background but it does not mean you have to think of BDD as it has anything to do with unit tests.

Your cases should be rather `Examples` so it will be translated into test cases in the background - but for you it should be transparent as it could be any other engine behind the curtains.

So - without knowing any further details - I would do it like this:

```
Scenario Outline: My fantastic test with multiple cases
    Given I have a <Path>
    When I perform a test
    Then the expected result is <Expected>

Examples:
| Path                       | Expected              |
| irm_xxx_lkdd_xuxt.csv.ovr  | 6677,6677_6677,3001,6 |
| irm_xxx_lkdd_fcvt.csv.ovrr | 6677,6677_6677,3001,6 |
| irm_xxx_lkdd_fbvt.csv.ovrr | 6677,6677_6677,3001,6 |
```

In the `Given` step you can store any configuration (maybe just storing a path is a too simple example), the `When` step is for doing the actual test, and finally, in the `Then` step you do the assertions.

```
[Binding]
public class MyFantasticFeatureBindings
{
    [Given("I have a (.*)")]
    public void ConfigureTest(string path)
    {
        // setup any configuration here - actually it can be the expected value, too
        ScenarioContext.Current.Set(path, nameof(path));
    }

    [When("I perform a test")]
    public void DoTest()
    {
        // obtain configuration, do the test and store the results and possible errors
        var path = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<string>("path");

        var result = PerformTest(path); // TODO - you have to implement this

        ScenarioContext.Current.Set(result, nameof(result)); 
    }

    [Then("the expected result is (.*)")]
    public void Assertions(string expectedResult)
    {
        var actualResult = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<string>("result");
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my post with my feature file. Under my examples i have different status. So for my 'Then' step once the batch is being executed from the 'When' step different measures will be generated. Once these measures are generated i want to 'Cat' the file and compare the output of the file with my expected result.

Comment: Ok, so it means you need N x M steps after all. But it does not change the main point of the answer: you need to take all of the needed data from the feature file and do not try to mix it explicitly with NUnit cases. Maybe my other answer here can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49182246/5114784

Comment: Yes i agree. But isn't there a way of combining the file path and expected result within my method? so essentially i can still use the code i have in the 'Then' step whereby i process the file path and compare the expected result.

Comment: Yes, if both the path and expected result are processed only in the `Then` step, it could be a reasonable solution.

Comment: Yes, they are only processed in the 'Then' Step. Using the example above how can i integrate the file path and expected result within the method

Comment: Just use two parameters: `[Then("the expected result taken from (.*) is (.*)")]` where first param can be `path` and the second one is `expectedResult`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172384/discussion-between-j-opendock-and-taffer).